# Dynamic generated form with Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm creating ZF2 Poll Module. I have poll with many questions. Every question has answers that can be multiple answers or single answer(Radio or MultiCheckbox). How to create a dynamic form that I can show to front-end?

This is what I've tried, but the form doesn't validate correctly...

**module\Polls\src\Polls\Form\PollFillingQuestionsForm.php**

```
  <?php
    namespace Polls\Form;

    use Zend\Form\Form;
    use Polls\Form\Fieldset\PollFillingQuestionAnswerFieldset;
    use Polls\Form\Fieldset\PollFillingQuestionFieldset;

    class PollFillingQuestionsForm extends Form {

    public function __construct($questionsObject) {
        parent::__construct('questionsForm');

        $questionsFieldset = new PollFillingQuestionFieldset('questions');

    //$questionsObject is array of question objects.
        foreach ($questionsObject as $questionObject) {
            $fieldset = new PollFillingQuestionAnswerFieldset($questionObject->id, array(), $questionObject);
                $questionsFieldset->add($fieldset);
            }

            $this->add($questionsFieldset);

            $this->add(array(
                'name' => 'submit',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'type' => 'submit',
                    'value' => 'Submit Poll',
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success',
                ),
            ));
        }
    }
```

**module\Polls\src\Polls\Form\Fieldset\PollFillingQuestionAnswerFieldset.php**

```
<?php

namespace Polls\Form\Fieldset;

use Polls\Model\QuestionAnswer;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ArraySerializable;

class PollFillingQuestionAnswerFieldset extends Fieldset {

public function __construct($name, $options, $questionObject) {
    parent::__construct($name, $options);

    $question = $questionObject;

    $this->setLabel($question->title);

    $type = 'Radio';
    $elementType = 'radio';
    switch ($question->answer_type) {
        case 'many':
            $type = 'MultiCheckbox';
            $elementType = 'checkbox';
            break;
        case 'one':
            $type = 'Radio';
            $elementType = 'radio';
            break;
        default:
            $type = 'Radio';
            $elementType = 'radio';
            break;
    }
    $this->setHydrator(new ArraySerializable())
            ->setObject(new QuestionAnswer());

    $answers = $question->getAnswers();

    $answerValues = array();
    foreach ($answers as $answer) {
        $answerValues[$answer->id] = $answer->title;
    }
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'answer',
        'type' => $type,
        'options' => array(
            'type' => $elementType,
            'value_options' => $answerValues,
        ),
    ));
}
}
```

Comment: I think, for a dynamic form, it might be an easier approach to use [an array, passing it to the form factory](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#creation-via-factory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this in the past, with a clean Factory strategy you can inject the dependencies into your form and your input filter.  The magic lies in your Factories.

Start by wiring things in your service manager config:

```
'form_elements' => [
    'factories' => [
        DynamicForm::class => DynamicFormFactory::class,
    ],
],

'input_filters' => [
    'factories' => [
        DynamicInputFilter::class => DynamicInputFilterFactory::class,          
    ],
],
```

First task is to get your FormFactory done up right.

```
class DynamicFormFactory implements FactoryInterface, MutableCreationOptionsInterface
{

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $options;

     /**
     * Set creation options
     *
     * @param  array $options
     * @return void
     */
    public function setCreationOptions( array $options )
    {
        $this->options = $options;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        /**
         * @var \Zend\Form\FormElementManager       $serviceLocator
         * @var \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager $serviceManager
         */
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        try
        {
            $options   = /* set up your form's config, you have the service manager here */;
            $form      = new DynamicForm( $options );

            $form->setInputFilter( $serviceManager->get('InputFilterManager')->get( DynamicFormFilter::class, $options ) );
        }
        catch( \Exception $x )
        {
            die( $x->getMessage() );
        }
        return $form;
    }       
}
```

Then, react to `$options` in your DynamicInputFilterFactory through the MutableCreationOptionsInterface implementation.  You generally don't want forms and filters to be 'option aware', let the factories take care of that.

```
class DynamicInputFilterFactory implements FactoryInterface, MutableCreationOptionsInterface
{

    protected $options;

    /**
     * Set creation options
     *
     * @param  array $options
     * @return void
     */
    public function setCreationOptions( array $options )
    {
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    public function createService( ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator )
    {
        /* do stuff with $this->options */

        return new DynamicInputFilter(
             /* pass your transformed options */
        );
    }   
}
```

Next, all you have to do is create your form and input filter per what was passed to them through MutableOptions.  Set your dependencies in `__construct` (don't forget to call parent::__construct) and initialize your form in `init` per the options passed in.

I suspect you have a good base in ZF2, so I'll stop here.  This ought to get you on your way.  Take-aways are MutableCreationOptionsInterface and separating your InputFilter and Form construction, combining the two in your Form Factory.

Comment: After this post, I went out and made a little CLI tool to rapidly write Form boilerplate: https://packagist.org/packages/saeven/zf2-form-builder